# jQuery's way of asserting an element with a certain ID exist in the page?

Tags: jquery

I was going to do `$("#foo") !== null` to assert that an element with the `id="foo"` does exist in the page, but it turns out even if the element doesn't exist, the selector `$("#foo")` still returns an object.

So to test whether the selector can find an element, should

```
assert($("#foo").length >= 1);
```

be used?  I also thought of using `assert($("#foo").is("div")` but if the HTML is changed, and the element is not a `div` but becomes a `p` or `span`, then it will break the assert.  What is a good, standard way to assert that the element does exist?

jsfiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/qnbAn/1/

Comment: Just `if ( $("#foo").length )` should do !

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
if ($("#foo").length){
    // element with id foo existed
}
```

Since id of an element is unique.

Comment: Your first conditional expression is always `true` even if `#foo` matches nothing. jQuery objects are objects, and objects are always `true` in a boolean context.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi true , fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use [length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to check if a given selector matches anything.

Selectors that match nothing result in empty jQuery objects, but even empty jQuery objects are valid instances and evaluate to `true` in a boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#elementId').Length > 0
```

like

[Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Do this in simple like this

```
if($("#mydiv").length){
 // mydiv exist
}
```